# Algorithm to find correct index

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have an array and a map. The array contains a list of numbers the map contains a key (integer) value (boolean) pair telling us which items have been removed from the list.

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

And a map telling us which items have been removed:

`{ 3: true, 4: true, 5: true, 6: true, 7: true, 8: true, 9: true }`

The items remain in the array, but are not counted toward the index when looking up an item in the array by index.

For example, given the above, index 2 would return 10:

`[1, 2, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, 10]`

`-0--1------------------------2-`

We can loop through each item in the list to see if it is in the map, but worst case the complexity would be O(n) and if there was one billion items in the list this would be a problem. Is there a better way to determine the correct index? I have thought of using a batch type binary tree - each node would hold a sequential range (if a sequential range exists), or a single number, but even then - if every other item was removed - worst case would be O(n) since there would be no sequential ranges.

Comment: _"Is there a better way to determine the correct index?"_ -- please clarify. Which index do you mean? The actual index in the array? E.g. `10`? Or the virtual index, based on the map? E.g. `2`? I think you are talking about the former, but since your question is so vague and broad, it's not really clear.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Sorry I tried to make it as clear as possible given what it is. The map tells us which items do not count towards the index. The list marked with "x" is a visualization of items that have been "removed" although they are still actually in the list index `2` should give us `10` (count item 1, 2, skip the x's, return 10)

Comment: All that said, given that you are intending to build a separate data structure to do this work anyway, why not just create a separate list of indexes? You'd have to adjust it every time the map changes, but then that'd be true for whatever data structure you choose. Fact is, what counts as a "good" solution really depends on a lot more than what you've shared above, such as how often the data will change, and what your usage pattern and requirement is for getting this index in the first place.

Comment: making initial list of next indices like [0:1, 1:2, 2:3, ..., n-1:-1] and updating backwards on removal will give a constant lookup. still takes linear time when element is removed/added

Comment: @mangusta the first thing that came to my mind was this one too. if there are not a lot of changes in map, I think this will be best.

Comment: You need a set of removed *indices*, rather than removed values.

Comment: @n.m. a sorted list of indexes would be even better than a set, since a binary search could immediately give you the number of deleted items before the index of interest.

Comment: @MarkRansom an array is an implementation of set, a set correctly implemented with a tree can do it too.

Comment: @n.m. if you're talking about a custom implementation of a set, sure. But the Python type `set` is based on hash maps and gives you nothing special except O(1) membership testing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a binary tree with an extra property that each node will hold the number of removed items in its subtree. update that value when you insert or remove an item.
To find the index of an item, find it on the tree and for every right turn in the search add the number of removed items of the left subtree.